# github collaborators vs organization

Tags: github

I need to have multiple people work on a private repository and was wondering why anyone would pay 9$/user as an organization if one can just have a single paid user with a private repository who adds other users as collaborators?

Comment: I'm not sure this question is on-topic, per https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: If you look at the [GitHub pricing scheme](https://github.com/pricing) under the $9/user per month plan, you will see the text `Team and user permissions`.  This does not appear under the $7/month plan.  There is definitely a difference between the two.  Whether this difference affects _you_ is another story.